# How to replace characters conditionally in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replace, str-replace

I have some text in a column of a SQL Server table such that:

```
text_col
-----------------------------------------------
{"hello:"a wing"}
{"This is your"s computer"}
{"long address:flower valley, green"s point"}
{"long address:"A wing, 3 cross road"}
```

Expected output:

```
text_col
-------------------------------------------------
{"hello:"a wing"}
{"This is your's computer"}
{"long address:flower valley, green's point"}
{"long address:'A wing, 3 cross road"}
```

What I wanted to do: I want to replace only those `"` with `'` if it is preceded by alphabets and ends with space.

This is what I had tried

```
UPDATE <table_name> 
SET <column_name> = REPLACE(<column_name>,'#','''') 
WHERE <condition...>
```

Any suggestion on the same will be helpful

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by 'end with space'? Your 2nd and 3rd lines do not actually end in space.

Comment: @SameerMahajan `your"s ` there is space after `"s `

Comment: Also at 4th line i.e `address:'A wing`  `'` is preceded by `:` a special character

Comment: @deepesh That's something that should be done while entering the data. SQL (not just T-SQL) isn't the best choice for string processing.

Comment: @deepesh besides, what you posted shows one string per row surrounded by `{"` and `"}`. You can treat these characters as delimiters, remove them from your string, replace double quotes in the *remainder* and rebuild the string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can't remove `{ }` because this text column is my JSON formatted string, and from these JSON I'm extracting some values.

Comment: @deepesh first, yes you can, and add them later. Second, that's not JSON. `{ }` defines a *dictionary* but your data contains a single string *only*. Did you post the wrong sample data perhaps? Or are you asking how to convert these strings to actual Json ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is sample text which is been stored in  a sql table column https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=19.055203,72.84442687

Comment: @deepesh this link returns an *error*. It doesn't matter anyway, becose `Maps` returns valid Json. Not what you posted here. The code that receives this Json string and stores it in the database ends up mangling it somehow. Or the sample you posted doesn't contain actual data. In any case, you *can* have double quotes as long as they are properly escaped.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos exactly that's what's my problem is, that text gets mangled up,for which I'm trying to get the json formatting done

Comment: @deepesh then post *your project's code* that does the mangling. It's not Google, it's not SQL Server, it's not .NET. That's not what the Geocode API returns. Did someone try to split the Json string to extract addresses, instead of parsing it perhaps?

Comment: While I have a list of lat and longt coordinates which I m accessing it and doing reverse geocoding and updating the JSON result in a sql table, all this is being done programmatically thru python

Comment: @deepesh if I try the map at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro the response is a *proper* Json string, with an `address_components` array that contains objects with attribute/value pairs like `"long_name" : "Greece","short_name" : "GR"`. Your data looks like someone tried to extract the components in the wrong way, removing the **required** double quotes after the keys. You don't need to replace or remove double quotes. You need to *add* the missing double quotes at the very lest.

Comment: @deepesh it doesn't make a lot of sense to fix the *mangled* data. You should find the broken import code and fix it. Until you do, you can fix these strings by replacing `:` with `":`. Also replace that `:'` with `:"`, eg `set text_col=REPLACE (text_col,':','":') where text_col not like '%":%'`

Comment: @deepesh anyway, it's not possible to help until you post the code that mangles the data. FYI, SQL Server 2016 and above provide JSON functions. You probably didn't need to shred the response anyway

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, for time being I can try the replace function you provided. But still I need to debug why the Json text is being mangled while being updated in a sql column... Thanks a lot for your suggestions...